# The “parentheses” of the composite functions

Tags: functions

The question requires me to show that the following statement is true or false.

Let $A,B$ be sets, and $f:A\to B$, $g:B\to A$ be functions. Suppose $g\circ f\circ g$ is surjective, and $f\circ g\circ f$ is injective. Then $f\circ g$ is bijective.

So basically I apply the fact that “if $g\circ f$ is surjective, then $g$ is surjective” and “if $g\circ f$ is injective, then $f$ is injective”.

But the problem is, can I read $f\circ g\circ f$ as both $f\circ (g\circ f)$ and $(f\circ g)\circ f$?

The purpose of doing this is to get “$g\circ f$ is surjective” and “$g\circ f$ is injective”. But I am not sure if it is legal.

Comment: Your question is about whether the composition of functions is associative. It is answered in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3678585/proof-verification-composition-of-maps-is-associative).

Comment: Yes you can read the composition in both forms, because its easy to prove that composition of functions is associative

Comment: Thank you! Got it now!